# I18n in ReactJs app of very large scale

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization

Do you have any experience with implementing internalization/localization in very large react app ?

We are talking about thousands of strings and some ~20 languages
Loading it all in browser is not a very good idea :) so should be done server-side. But im not sure that if even sending whole file for one language (e.g all translations for en_US )is a good idea.

Is there an option to achieve getting server side  only `nestedStrings` from translations json like this

```
{
  topLevel : "a",
  topLevel2 : "b",
    nestedProperty : {
        someting : "C"
    }
```

Or should i write custom solution ?

Comment: It's definitely possible for you to write some kind of REST service that serves up subsets of your data. Are you asking if such a system already exists? Because 1) [that type of question would be considered off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and 2) it would depend on your server technology.

Comment: If this could, help, I personally use [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/getting-started.html) which is based on i18next. It allows you to handle multiple languages on multiple namespaces to chunk files for big projects like yours. This is opinionated so just take it as a way to do things instead of a real answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-i18next (https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next) like mentioned in the comments, plus:

- you can split up translations per module, like doing code splitting (all there already - no extra work)
- i18next would also run on most server envs if you need that too: https://www.i18next.com/supported-frameworks.html (not all can / should be done in client)
- BONUS: on that scale you will need a translation management tool keeping up with your development -> there is https://locize.com which comes from the same team and enables an amazing workflow -> see the sample with auto adding content to your translation project, incontext editing, ... https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/locize-example (video link in readme)

Comment: Codesplitting is not that easy since you only know the language at runtime. You would need an extra step to create a chunk per language. https://github.com/whitecolor/lp-loader seems to do just that. Maybe there are others as well.